# Android Date format error

Tags: java, android, simpledateformat

While Formatting a Date using SimpleDateFormat, I get the date and the month right. But the Year is Decreased by one. What could be the problem?

```
public static String getFormattedDate(String date) {

    SimpleDateFormat sourceFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS");
    Date testDate = null;
    String newFormat="space";

    try {
        testDate = sourceFormat.parse(date);
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("d/MMM/yyyy");
        newFormat = formatter.format(testDate);
        Log.i("Formatted Date",newFormat);
    }catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    return newFormat;
}
```

The Actual date and the Formatted dates are

```
 01-04 15:34:00.233 21858-21858/com.cube_me.cubeme I/Actual Date: 2016-12-19 00:00:00
 01-04 15:34:00.233 21858-21858/com.cube_me.cubeme I/Formatted Date: 19/Dec/2015
```

Comment: Your source format is 4-digit-year, 2-digit-minute, 2-digit day in month, 2-digit hours, 2-digit month, 2-digit milliseconds. Is that really what you want? IMHO it should be `"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"` -> remember, date formats are case sensitive!

Comment: Changing the Minutes and seconds to lower case, fixed the problem. Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 5):

It's because you have a mistake here:

```
yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS
```

it should be

```
yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss
```

So, you misplaced minutes (`mm`) with months (`MM`). If you pass 00 as a month, then you get December (00 is before 01 so it's parsed to 12), previous year which is correct.

Also `SS` are for milliseconds and `ss` gives you seconds.

Check the letters table [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Answer (score -1):

Use

```
SimpleDateFormat sourceFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:SS");
```

instead of

```
SimpleDateFormat sourceFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS");
```